# кнопка не реагирует

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox

после установки проверки на checkbox и удаления свойства `disabled` кнопка никак не откликается на нажатия, ни один способ прослушивания клика не работает, почему это может быть?

```js
function on() {
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');

  if (document.querySelector('input').checked == false) {
    btn.style.background = "red";
    btn.style.color = "black";
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    btn.style.cursor = "default";
  } else {
    btn.style.background = "white";
    btn.disabled = "false";
    btn.style.color = "black";
    btn.style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
}

on();

function con() {
  console.log(1)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="on()">
  <button onclick="con()">
  отправить
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function on() {
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');

  if (!document.querySelector('input').checked) {
    btn.style.background = "red";
    btn.style.color = "black";
    btn.disabled = true;              // <---
    btn.style.cursor = "default";
  } else {
    btn.style.background = "white";
    btn.style.color = "black";
    btn.disabled = false;             // <---
    btn.style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
}

on();

function con() {
  console.log(1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="on()">
  <button type='button' onclick="con()">
  отправить
</button>
</form>
```